# Bash - Printing string containing array item causes an odd graphic error - No special characters inside the array

Tags: bash

I am going crazy to understand why the following bash portion of code:

```
    simpleTest=("this is just a test print string after my array ${testArray[i]} keep testing")
echo $simpleTest
```

Prints the string like this[image]

As you can see, the part of the string that comes after ${testArray[I]} is then printed at the beginning of the line and is overriding the "This is just". Unfortunately I can't post the entire code but the rest of the code is pretty much independent. If I end my string at ${testArray[I]} everything works fine. I really don't understand why it doesn't accept other strings after the array item. There are no special characters inside the array

Any suggestion?

Comment: You probably have a `\r` character in your `testArray`.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the values inside testArray are one single word no signs

Comment: How can I reopen this thread? Someone has closed it without even check that this was actually a duplicated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions

Comment: I'd suggest editing the question to show us how `testArray` is being created, preferably in the form of a [mcve].  Otherwise we can only guess what the problem could be.